# Is there any way to export a custom Ribbon stored inside an .xlsm file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this .xlsm file with a custom Ribbon. It has 8 buttons assigned to custom macros. Is there a way to extract the custom Ribbon into an .xlam?
If not, is there any way to open that custom Ribbon from another .xlsm?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the end goal is, but [RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor) might be helpful.

Comment: Also see here for a how to and sample: https://www.contextures.com/excelribbonaddcustomtab.html

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code to extract the CustomUI file from the Excel-File. It creates a copy of the file from which then the customUI14.xml file gets extracted.
Assumption: C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe is available

I added this piece of code to sourcetools.xla to not only extract the modules but also the customUI for versioning.

```vb
Public Sub extractCustomUIToFolder(wb As Workbook, pathTarget As String)
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = wb.Path & "~temp.xlsm"
    wb.SaveCopyAs tmp

    Dim strShellString As String

    strShellString = "e " & Chr$(34) & tmp & Chr$(34) & _
                     " -o" & Chr$(34) & pathTarget & "\" & Chr$(34) & _
                     " customUI14.xml -r -aoa"
                     
    Dim exePath As String
    exePath = Chr$(34) & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & Chr$(34) & " "
    
    Call Shell(exePath & strShellString)
    
    Kill tmp
End Sub
```

Using the according commands it is also possible to "re-import" the customUI14.xml file into the xlam

Answer (score -2):

The only documentation I can find about importing and exporting custom ribbons is [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T007790_Transferring_Ribbon_Customizations.html)

and [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-microsoft-excels-ribbon)

1. Click File
2. Select Options.
3. Select Customize Ribbon.
4. Select Import/Export.
5. Select Export all Customizations.
6. Choose a destination and file name in the File Save window.
7. Click Save to finish.